# How does the spacing with '\t' work?

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm trying to understand how the command '\t' work. I've just written the following code

```
fic4 = open('name.txt','w')
for k in range(100):
    x = k/100
    y = x**2+3.5
    z = x
    fic4.write(str(x) + '\t' + str(y) + '\t' + str(z) + '\n')
fic4.close()
```

and it gives me the following result

[image: the result]

I don't understand why (and how) the spacing varies from one line to another. Can someone explain this phenomenon to me?

Comment: `\t` is a tabulation. The second value of your 2 last rows exceed the 3rd and 4th tabulation so the third value is pushed to the 5th tabulation. It is identical to pressing TAB on most text editor.

Comment: Tab will push the print to the next `8` multiple

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Python. If I understand correctly, the shell decides how characters sent to stdout are displayed. You'd see the same behavior in a C or Java program.

Comment: @RafaelC always 8?